# What is wrong with my plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, debugging, bugs

My plot as shown below is not reflecting the upper cap surface exactly as I have defined it (I simply negated the z-ordinate of the parametric equations)

Is this some kind of numerical bug?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myangle}{90}
\begin{axis}[axis equal image, axis lines=none, ticks=none, view/h=120, view/v=20]
%cylindrical faces
    %\addplot3[surf, shader=interp, point meta={cos(\myangle)*x+sin(\myangle)*y}, colormap={grayslate}{rgb255=(200,200,200)rgb255=(0,0,0)}, opacity=0.75, z buffer = sort, samples = 35, 
    %variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = 0:360, y domain = -2:2, ] ({1+cos(u)}, {sin(u)}, {(1 + floor(-v/(abs(-v)+1)) - floor(v/(abs(v)+1)))*max(-sqrt(4 - 2*x),v)/2 + (1 + floor(v/(abs(v)+1)) - floor(-v/(abs(-v)+1)))*min(sqrt(4 - 2*x),v)/2});
%spherical faces
    \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, colormap={custom}{rgb255=(100,100,100)rgb255=(250,250,250)}, z buffer = sort, samples = 35,
    variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = 0:1, y domain = 0:180] ({u(1+cos(2*v))}, {u*sin(2*v)}, {2*sqrt(1- u*u*cos(v)^2)});
    \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, colormap={custom}{rgb255=(100,100,100)rgb255=(250,250,250)}, z buffer = sort, samples = 35,
    variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = 0:1, y domain = 0:180] ({u(1+cos(2*v))}, {u*sin(2*v)}, {-2*sqrt(1- u*u*cos(v)^2)});
%window
    \addplot3+[domain=0:720, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, black, thin]({1+cos(x)},{sin(x)},{2*sin(x/2)});
\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you aren't just looking on the inside of the upper cap, and if you rotated your viewport you'd be able to see the feature?

Comment: this is not a cone

Comment: Sorry, I meant the upper cap. Do you think you could just be looking at the inside of the upper cap from below, with it not being shaded like you expect?

Comment: the upper cap is definitely smooth; but I have opted to use a different parametrisation of my surface, so I don't think this question is necessary any longer. but i will keep it up and take your answer for completeness.